# Filtrando itens em uma tabela produtos

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, winforms, visual-studio

Boa tarde a todos, estou com uma aplicação simples que estou desenvolvendo, e estou com o seguite problema, eu tenho uma variavel "listaItensToras"que nela ja tem os ID dos itens, e tenho uma variavel listaToras que tem todas as as Toras cadastradas, criei uma variavel filtrados para receber de dentro da ListaToras os itens que estao na variavel listaItensToras, tenho um exemplo que fiz porem nao estou conseguindo filtrar.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `listaItensToras` é um tipo de dado e `c.AlceId` é de outro tipo por isso a comparação não é aceita!

Comment: tentei de varias formas porem nao consegui, amigo tem alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ItensToras deve conter a propriedade AlceId, assim você pode verifica se a Tora esta na listaItensToras, assim ficara seu foreach

```
foreach(var tora in listaToras)
{
   if(listaItensToras.Any(x => x.AlceId == tora.AlceId))
   {
      filtrados.Add(tora);
   }
}
```

Para saber se um determinado valor esta presente em uma lista utilizamos o método `.Any()` da biblioteca [System.Linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-5.0) que retorna um `true` caso exista o valor dentro da lista ou `false` caso contrario.

Comment: muito obrigado amigo, Deus te abençoe vou fazer o teste aqui acredito que agora vai da certo.

Comment: Opa, espero que de certo mesmo, não esqueça de marca como aceita a resposta. Vlw